# finding duplicates using java 8

Tags: java, java-8

I have an employee class with id, name and address fields. Two employees are considered the same if their id and name are exactly same. Now I have a list of employees, now my task is to get the collection of duplicate employees.

Here is my code for Employee class with hascode and equals methods overriden based on id and name fields.

```
class Employee {
    int id;
    String name;
    String address;

    public Employee(int id, String name, String address) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.address = address;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Employee [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", address=" + address + "]";
    }


    // auto generated by eclipse based on fields for id and name    
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + id;
        result = prime * result + ((name == null) ? 0 : name.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Employee other = (Employee) obj;
        if (id != other.id)
            return false;
        if (name == null) {
            if (other.name != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!name.equals(other.name))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

}
```

Now I have this code to find the duplicate employees

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Employee e1 = new Employee(1, "John", "SFO");
    Employee e2 = new Employee(2, "Doe", "NY");
    Employee e3 = new Employee(1, "John", "NJ");

    List<Employee> list = Arrays.asList(e1, e2, e3);

    Set<Employee> set = new HashSet<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < list.size(); j++) {
            if (list.get(i).equals(list.get(j))) {
                set.add(list.get(i));
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println(set);
}
```

This code works fine and gives me employee with id 1 in my set.

How to do the same operation using Java 8 lamda's and streams? Is `flatmap` is helpful in this case?

Comment: you can do the same logic of your nested loops using the following code               
   `System.out.println(list.stream().filter(em -> list.indexOf(em) > -1 && list.get(list.indexOf(em)) != em).collect(Collectors.toSet()));`

Comment: What is expected result here? `new Employee(1, "John", "SFO")` and `new Employee(1, "John", "NJ")` both are considered as duplicates of each other. Do you want to get **both** of them or maybe only **one** (in which case what is criteria which one you want to select)? IMO getting duplicates means gathering *all* separate elements which can be considered as equal.

Comment: OR maybe you want to get just one *representative* of each "class of employees" regardless which one from that class it was?

Comment: Doesn't `java.util.HashSet` exist for this reason?

Answer (score 1):

Your requirement if kinda specific and not really helpful in most cases. I would do something like that instead:

```java
final Map<Employee, Long> groupedWithCount = employees.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
```

Now you have all the info you need, and more. Employees are grouped by count in this map, for your data it looks like that:

```
{
  Employee [id=2, name=Doe, address=NY] = 1,
  Employee [id=1, name=John, address=SFO] = 2
}
```

Obviously, duplicates are entries with value > 1.

Comment: It may be worth mentioning that this would gather only one *representative* from group of equal employees who will be placed as key. If we want to get that group instead we can use `Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity())` instead and get `Map<Employee, List<Employee>>` where each `List<Employee>` will hold all "equal" employees.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach:

```
list.stream()
    .collect(groupingBy(identity(), counting()))        
    .entrySet()
    .stream()
    .filter(e -> e.getValue() != 1)
    .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
    .collect(toList());
```

or :

```
list.stream()
    .collect(groupingBy(identity()))        
    .values()
    .stream()
    .filter(l -> l.size() != 1)
    .map(l -> l.get(0))                 // The list cannot be empty
    .collect(toList());
```